# Definition of a smooth complete integral pointed algebraic curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Can anybody give me a reference to understand the definition of "a smooth complete integral pointed algebraic curve"?

I'm beginning to study the paper "upper bounds for the dimension of moduli spaces of curves with symmetric weierstrass semigroups" of professor André Contiero and Karl Otto, and have problems already on the first line with that definition. Is there a place where I can find the definition of that kind of curve?

Comment: This sounds like material you can read from Hartshorne's book.

Answer (score 1):

This should be understood as a connected, compact Riemann surface [algebraicaly: irreducible, reduced ("= integral") smooth algebraic variety of dimension one ("curve") that admits an embedding into a projective space as a Zariski closed subset(projetive, which is equivalent to "complete" in the curve case)], with a point on it specified ("=pointed").

Comment: Does "Specified a point" mean that fix a point in the curve?